# Relevance of Metro to ASP.Net developer?

Tags: web-development, javascript, asp.net, metro

I am a web developer, working mostly with ASP.Net(webforms + MVC), C#, javascript and so on.

As you know, continuous learning is very important for us, but time is not infinite. I do dabble with the odd technology every now and then that has nothing to do with web but mostly I try to learn more about my field in order to became better at my job.

I have the opportunity to attend either a ASP.Net MVC short course or a Metro app short course and not sure which to pick. On the one hand I feel like I would already know 75% of the MVC course material so would not get as much out of it as with the Metro course. but on the other hand I ask myself how useful is a metro course going to be in my future of being a web developer. I could always dabble in it again when I have the time?

So my real question is, is there any real benefit to a web developer using his time to learn Metro specifically, instead of something else like knockout.js or some other tec that could actually be of use to me in my daily work life?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well if you're into hobbyist software development and think you can make something like WP or W8 app in your spare time go for the Metro thing.

It might also give you some insight into how the MVVM pattern works in other contexts than knockout.js.

That being said, there's nothing like someone actually showing you how a product you are using should be used (I'm talking about mvc 3). Also, this is a great opportunity for networking and finding out what other people are doing with this framework, giving you the opportunity to evaluate your knowledge on the subject against other developers.

Bottom line is if you aren't interested in desktop/embedded development at all go for the mvc 3 course.